# Why are the Elves always shown as having thoughts about leaving this world for some utopia rather than reveling in their life on Earth?

Tags: elves, fantasy-genre, trope

Is this trope there to reinforce the belief that Elves are a superior race, come from somewhere else and they don't have the vigour and childish imagination of the more mundane races to find peace in physical tasks, rather they prefer to find their peace in Tranquility of the Divine?

It creates a rather sad nostalgic moment for me, when I, in the shoes of men and dwarves realize that there is no "elder, beautiful" race watching over me.

Examples are Undying lands in LOTR series, Isle of Evermore in Age of Wonders series, Arlathan in Dragon Age, Feywild in DnD?

Comment: Many fantasy tropes boil down to, "Well Tolkien did it..."

Comment: Kreacher disagrees

Comment: Since this question has been closed, it's only here that I can point out the [Tuatha Dé Danaan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuatha_D%C3%A9_Danann) were forced to move to the Otherworld [Tír na nÓg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C3%ADr_na_n%C3%93g) after being defeated in battle by the Milesians.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Because of Tolkien**

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elves_in_fiction#Other_examples_of_elves) is a list of Fantasy works from Wikipedia that features elves. The *Tolkienesque* elves usually postdate popularisation of Lord of the Rings. However, the portrayal of elves is not limited to these works. Off the top of my head,

*Dragonlance Elves:* They are neither particularly righteous nor very advanced compared to men. They are slightly weaker than men and have some tendency towards magic. They are not really seeking to leave their surroundings for somewhere, as opposed to the Middle-earth Elves, and they can really be racist.

*Harry Potter Elves:* Completely opposite portrayal of elves compared to the Lord of the Rings.

*Might and Magic Elves:* They are good bowmen and have some magical relations with nature. Yet they are neither superior to men nor are they trying to leave Enroth, even though Gelu the half-elf accidentally destroyed Enroth.

*Christmas Elves:* I don't think they are in a hurry to leave the world.

The list can be expanded as more and more fantasy works are created. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elves_in_fiction#Countering_the_Tolkien_tradition) is again a Wikipedia list of fantasy works portraying non-Tolkienesque elves.

**To sum up, there is no such trope. Yet it looks like there is one because of Tolkien.**

Comment: fwiw - I don't believe house-elves are ever referred to as anything other than house-elves in Harry Potter (ie - not just 'elves') which may denote they are a distinctly different archetype. Tolkien took great pains to make a distinction between 'elfin' and 'elvin' - his elves were not elfs (though the spelling does appear in the text as well) - so, comparing them to Christmas elfs, and possibly even house-elves may be incorrect if such a thing can be correct / incorrect)

Comment: @NKCampbell You might be right. I just tried to list all possible elves that I could think of. Yet, HP Elves were listed in the wikipedia page, so there is some credibility in keeping them here.

Comment: I'm surprised that Wikipedia link didn't mention the elves from Ramond F Feist's [Magician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magician_(Feist_novel)) series.  They definitely don't have their collective heads in the clouds.

Comment: @PeterM Feel free to edit my answer to include the Magician elves. Somewhere below Dragonlance and over HP works :)

Comment: @C.Koca You've already proved your point, so adding one more type is kind of moot.  Besides  I'm sure that there are a large number of other Elves that also could be added .  My surprise is at the wikipedia article.  Plus it's been a long while since I read that series.

Comment: That elves exist that don't use the trope doesn't mean the trope doesn't exist. Tropes aren't universal, and can be ignored or even subverted.

Comment: @harebeck The are no universal rules governing tropes, so I don't think there is one in this context. But, if there is one, it is because of Tolkien. I checked every one of the tolkienesque elves in the Wikipedia list and all of them postdates LotR.

Comment: For another example of Elves that don’t follow the trope, the Elves of Discworld are actively trying to *enter* the world, not leave it.

Comment: This answer ignores Tolkien's likely borrowing of the [otherworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celtic_Otherworld), summer lands, fair isles to west, etc. from Welsh, Aurthurian and Irish mythology.

Comment: @Lexible can you elaborate ? Or write a separate answer?

Comment: @user1194497 Read the otherworld link?